# Prevent stroke border from overflowing path

Tags: html, canvas, border, stroke

`strokeRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);` draws a full rectangle but the line width is cut in half, here is an example:

```
<canvas></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName ("canvas");

    var lineWidth = 10;

    var canvasHeight = canvas[0].height;
    var canvasWidth = canvas[0].width;

    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext ("2d");

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;

    ctx.strokeRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
</script>
```

[image: screenshot of problem]

I can fix that but isn't elegant:

```
<canvas></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName ("canvas");

    var lineWidth = 10;

    var canvasHeight = canvas[0].height - lineWidth;
    var canvasWidth = canvas[0].width - lineWidth;

    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext ("2d");

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;

    lineWidth /= 2;

    ctx.strokeRect (lineWidth, lineWidth, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
</script>
```

[image: screenshot of inelegant solution]

Is there a native method to do that ? Something like the "box-sizing" css3 attribute:

```
canvas {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to double the lineWidth, but other than that and your own solution I think that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strokes in HTML5 Canvas—as in Adobe Illustrator or SVG—are always centered on the path that they are stroking. Long ago I [proposed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2003Oct/0000.html) a [new SVG property](http://phrogz.net/svg/stroke-location.svg) that sounds like what you want, but this functionality is in neither SVG nor Canvas. **Your stroke is behaving as it is supposed to.**

However, **you can work around this** by using [clipping region](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#clipping-region), clipping to the same as the path you are about to stroke and doubling your nominal lineWidth:

```
function clippedRectStroke( ctx, x, y, w, h ){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x,y);
  ctx.lineTo(x,y+h);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w,y+h);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w,y);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.lineWidth *= 2;
  ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
  ctx.restore(); 
};
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dvz9Y/2/

Comment: One feature I've been wanting for more than 25 years would be an option to adjust the meaning of "miter limit" so that rather than converting a miter join to a bevel (which is guaranteed to look ugly) it would chop off the tip of the miter at a distance of (miter limit times line width) from the intersection of the centers of the two lines.  If one wants things to look like a miter limit of 1 "should" look, one could accomplish this appearance by setting the miter limit to 1.42 or greater and, and each corner, inserting an infintesimal-length line perpendicular to the bisecting angle, but...

Comment: ...that only works with a "pseudo-miter-limit" of one and is rather awkward in any case.  Do you know if anyone has proposed anything like that, or do you know of any place where proposing such ideas might have an effect?